# Вопрос по функции openssl_encrypt (PHP)

Tags: php, ssl, шифрование, openssl

Здрaвствуйте. Я шифрую строку при помощи функции `openssl_encrypt`.

```
$string = 'hello';
$password = '1234567812345678';
$vector = 'vector1234567890';
echo "Результат: " . openssl_encrypt ($string, "AES-128-CBC",  $password, 0, $vector );
```

Получаю следующую строку:

```
Результат: YZFtMwTpa8x44OiA6Kt/0w==
```

Вопрос: как дешифровать эту строку при помощи библиотеки `OpenSSL`? Я установил библиотеку, пробовал разные команды, но в результате ничего не получилось. Можете дать команду, которая возьмёт эту строку `YZFtMwTpa8x44OiA6Kt/0w==` и декодирует её обратно в `hello`?

Команда должна выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -e -in text1.txt -out text2.txt -base64 -pass pass:1234567812345678 -iv vector1234567890 -p
```